# Connecting LEDs via Joy-IT ProtoShield+ GPIO

Tags: gpio, led

I am starting my first Raspberry Pi project and want to start with controlling some LEDs. I bought a Joy-IT ProtoShield+ (https://joy-it.net/en/products/RB-Proto+) for prototyping but I do not understand it's wiring and the only documentation I found is this image: [image: Joy-IT ProtoShield+]

As the LEDs are connected via a wire, I would like to connect them via the screw connections. Furthermore I would like to solder the resistor onto the breadboard.

So I would like to make a connection from one of the GPIO pins to the breadboard, insert a resistor into the circuit and then connect to a screw connection. Can you help me with that?

Comment: `the only documentation I found is this image` ... look at your board ... it has documentation printed on it

Comment: May I suggest that you use a wireless breadboard while you're still experimenting.